# Apply github commits programmatically

Tags: magento2, git, github

I have a customer Magento 2 website, created, i don't know by composer command or with web wizard method, in the root folder, there's a git folder,
I would like to apply those commits https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20277#issuecomment-458397222 to the Magento 2.2.4, the commits are in the 2.3.1 version
Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can apply this like composer patches. Check here how to do that https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching.html

Comment: That method doesn't always work https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/magento-2-3-upgrade-magento-inventory-msi/294417#294417